# How to build a taxonomy filter for drilling down search results?

Tags: low-search

How would I build a taxonomy filter like this in EE?

http://webcodesigner.com/?post_type=listing

I've already purchased Low Search, are there any other addons necessary for this kind of thing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In short:

- Create a [search form](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#form-tag);
- Create a [results list](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags#results-tag);
- Optionally use JavaScript to submit the form when one of its elements changes.

Depending on how your channels and fields are set up, you either want to hard-code the different options in your Form, or generate them using native channel tags or add-ons like [Loopee](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/loopee) or [Low Options](https://github.com/low/low_options).

To get a good grasp of how Low Search works, read the docs:

- Learn how Low Search approaches [parameters](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/parameters);
- Learn which parameters belong to which [filters](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters);
- Apply these parameters to the [template tags](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/tags);
- Check out the [advanced examples](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/examples).

Note: the only thing Low Search will not do, is generate a number of search results next to each filter option, like on the example site you linked.

Comment: Thanks for your quick support! After skimming the docs, I'm pretty sure Low Search + Loopee will be the right tools for the job.